# SRID for New York City 2010 Census Shapefile

Tags: postgis, shapefile, census, srid

I pulled the New York City census tract PostGIS from [Todd Schneider's work](https://github.com/toddwschneider/nyc-taxi-data), but I am struggling to find the correct SRID.

> PROJCS["NAD_1983_StatePlane_New_York_Long_Island_FIPS_3104_Feet",GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",984250.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-74.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",40.66666666666666],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",41.03333333333333],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",40.16666666666666],UNIT["Foot_US",0.3048006096012192]]

When I upload the above contents of the PRJ file to [prj2epsg](http://prj2epsg.org/search) as suggested by [this SE question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541202/how-do-you-know-what-srid-to-use-for-a-shp-file?rq=1), for instance, it fails to find a match.

Comment: mmm is it possible prj2epsg is not working or I'm doing something wrong?  I looked up Zillow's nyc neighborhood SRID which I looked up yesterday (4269) and it doesn't appear to be working.

Comment: Zilow's prj is much more simple: GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]

Comment: http://prj2epsg.org/search says "Invalid WKT syntax" for both.

Comment: EPSG:2263 from http://www.epsg-registry.org. The WKT is from Esri.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't have an EPSG code. I looked it up on spatialreference.org with

```
NAD_1983_StatePlane_New_York_Long_Island_FIPS_3104_Feet
```

Came up with http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/102718/

It's `ESRI:102718` which is in the proprietary ESRI namespace. The International Association of Oil & Gas Producers (OGP) Surveying & Positioning Committee maintains the proper EPSG codes.

This is the [statement I would use to add it to PostGIS](http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/102718/postgis/)

```
INSERT into spatial_ref_sys (srid, auth_name, auth_srid, proj4text, srtext)
values
( 9102718, 'esri', 102718, '+proj=lcc +lat_1=40.66666666666666 +lat_2=41.03333333333333 +lat_0=40.16666666666666 +lon_0=-74 +x_0=300000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +to_meter=0.3048006096012192 +no_defs ', 'PROJCS["NAD_1983_StatePlane_New_York_Long_Island_FIPS_3104_Feet",GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",984249.9999999999],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-74],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",40.66666666666666],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",41.03333333333333],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",40.16666666666666],UNIT["Foot_US",0.30480060960121924],AUTHORITY["EPSG","102718"]]');
```

**This will give it an effective PostGIS reference of `9102718`.** However, it shows here that the authority is `ESRI` and the authority has it as `102718`.

Comment: I'm definitely not understanding something because this appears incorrect.  The postGIS http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/102718/postgis/ does not match the original.

Comment: definitely esri:102718 - http://epsg.io/102718

Comment: but see also http://epsg.io/?q=new+york+nad83 - to see possible epsg codes that will match

Comment: So why doesn't the PRJ file match with the postgis as Boundless http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/loading_data.html seems to suggest it should?  They for instance use SRID: 26918 for their New York data.

Comment: That *may* match. I don't think NAD83 and the term New York is sufficient to establish the all of the parameters here.

Comment: As I look further Todd's code uses 4326 in some places (populate_green_trips), but that doesn't make a lot of sense either.

Comment: Can you please include a link to the official EPSG registry?  Spatialreference.org ain't it.